# ¿ Propiedades , Arrays , Estructura JSON dentro de una función de una librería YUI?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Buenas.
Estoy aprendiendo Javascript , JQuery , JSON , CodeIgniter

Me he encontrado con este fragmento de código de la librería YUI de JavaScript  "si no me equivoco" de una practica que me han pasado para aprender CodeIgniter

¿ Podéis ayudarme a razonar el código ?

```
<script language="javascript">
YUI().use( // Invoco la clase.
'aui-image-cropper', // parámetro
function(Y) { // función anónima 
var imageCropper = new Y.ImageCropper( // "Corregirme" creo que se crea 1 objeto tipo 'Y' la cual tiene 1 función por parametros una estructura JSON o un Array ? 
  {
  srcNode: '#myImage', // ¿Qué es esto ? ¿Propiedades del objeto clave valor de imageCropper o un elemento de JSON ?
  preserveRatio: true, 
  cropHeight: 80, 
  x: 0, 
  y: 0 
  }
).render(); // Le asocia a la función , otra función propia de la clase Y
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te aparece?¿Cuál es el resultado que esperas?

Comment: No se realmente el tipo de datos que hay entre las llaves { srcNode: '#myImage', ...etc } , No sé sí es un array asociativo , una propiedad o una estructura JSON

Comment: Es un objeto cuya representación en texto podría ser un JSON, como casi todo en js

Comment: Genial Gracias por la aclaración , no estaba seguro si era una propiedad ,  atributo , array o una estructura de datos de JSON

Answer (score 1):

> **Nota:** YUI es una librería declarada **sin soporte desde Octubre del 2014**. Muchas cosas han cambiado desde esa fecha en ECMAScript y tendencias de programación. Su uso se considera **no recomendado**.

YUI es una librería que en su época fue bastante popular en la comunidad. Desarrollada por Yahoo!, esta librería te permitía construir RIAs con relativa facilidad.

El fragmento de código que has puesto hace uso de una funcionalidad de YUI que sirve para **recortar imágenes**. Esto se hace mediante la función `YUI#ImageCropper`, que es un método de instancia.

La forma de crear instancias en YUI es mediante la función `use` o mediante `new`, el cual recibe una cantidad de parámetros opcionales. Si los parámetros son una serie de strings, **significa que se usarán dichos módulos** de YUI; si no se van a usar módulos, puede dejarse la llamada a dicha función sin parámetros o se le puede pasar un objeto de configuración.

Esto:

```
YUI.use('modulo1', 'modulo2', function (Y) { ... });
```

Es lo mismo que:

```
var Y = new YUI('modulo1', 'modulo2');
```

Respecto al código dentro del callback, solo se corta la imagen en `myImage`, preservando el aspect ratio, cortando 80 pixeles. Por último, la función `render` renderiza los cambios en el DOM.

Comment: Muchas gracias . la explicación esta genial , he aprendido mucho con tu aportación pero quería saber si los `srcNode` , `preserveRatio` , `cropHeight` son **propiedades** de estos modulos o son otro tipo de datos como **arrays asociativos** o elementos de tipo **JSON.** es la gran duda que tengo.

Comment: Imagina que creas una función para cortar una imagen. ¿Qué esperas que el usuario haga, que el decida las dimensiones o que la librería lo haga con las medidas que quiera sin darle opción? Para eso es dicho objeto; **es un objeto de configuración** que dicha función leerá para proceder a realizar el cortado. No existen los arrays asociativos en JavaScript, usas objetos en su lugar. No te confundas, los objetos JavaScript son similares a la notación JSON, pero no lo son.

Comment: Muchas gracias por compartir tus conocimientos.